# Promise in while loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generalize a script that encrypts forms using OpenPGP libraries.
I got some troubles with the client-side code (Javascript) :

```
var working = formID.elements[0];
var counter = 0;

while (working) {
    encrypt(working.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
        console.log("processing");
        working.value = encrypted_msg;
    });
    console.log("assuming processed");
    var counter = counter + 1;
    var working = formID.elements[counter];
}
```

The following code should take each form element and encrypt its value. However, the while loop doesn't wait for the asynchronous encrypt() function to be resolved.

I think i need to use promises in this case, but i have no idea how and the few tutorials didn't work in a while loop.

Help ?

Comment: are you using any framework angular/react for frontend or pure javascript?

Comment: @AkashBhandwalkar Only pure javascript and JQuery.

Comment: I answered. I hope it will work!

Comment: You can use recursive function also. Like call function on success of first asynchronus call

Comment: @Square, is the next form element encryption dependent on the previous?

Comment: @Maximus No, each encryption only depends on the value of the working element.

Comment: @Square, then Akash solution should be OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably can be used list of jQuery deferreds, something like this:

```
var deferreds = [];

$.each(formID.elements, function(key, working){

    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    deferreds.push(deferred);

    encrypt(working.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
        console.log("processing");
        working.value = encrypted_msg;
        deferred.resolve();
    });

});

$.when.apply( $, deferreds ).done(function(){
    console.log( 'after all encryptions!' );
});
```

Of course, can be used native `Promise` object instead `$.Deferred`, however I think `$.Deferred` is [more cross-browser way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

**UPD2:**

Improved answer based on native `Promise` and [`Promise.resolve()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) (thanks to @Bergi). For the case when `encrypt()` returns correct promise, method `Promise.resolve()` can be skipped.

```
var promises = [];

$.each(formID.elements, function(key, working){

    var promise = Promise.resolve(encrypt(working.value))
        .then(function(encrypted_msg) {
            console.log("processing");
            working.value = encrypted_msg;
        });

    promises.push(promise);

});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
    console.log( 'after all encryptions!' );
});
```

Comment: In theory, yes, but [avoid the deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi  Yes, it is bad practice to create excess deferreds/promices. But I don't know what object returns `encrypt` method and how it will work with `$.when()` or `Promise.all()`. The fact that this object contains `.then` method, not much to say about him.

I updated answer without antipattern.

Comment: @IStranger If you don't know what it returns, you can always use `Promise.resolve(encrypt(…))` (or `$.when(encrypt(…))` in jQuery), that's what they are for.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, it is awesome method). I like similar methods that allows to unify type without `if` statements and additional abstract layers. I improved answer using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var iterator = [];
for (var counter = 0; counter < formID.elements.length; counter++) {
    var working = formID.elements[counter];
    iterator.push(encrypt(working.value));
}

Promise.all(iterator)
.then(fumction(data){
    //Here you have all data
})
```

You can synchronize your operation like this way. By collecting all asynchronus value references and point to them when they have data.

In case your data is dependent.

```
function myfunction(previousValue){
    if(breaking Condition){
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return encrypt(working.value).then(function(encrypted_msg) {
        working.value = encrypted_msg;
        return myfunction(working);
    });
}
```

Comment: One problem tho, I need to pass the working var to the iterator too. How can i achieve that ?

Comment: Had an error, undefined working var. Still trying to make it work, tho.